# Efficiently handling a list of RDDs

Tags: apache-spark

I'm looking for a way to handle a List of RDDs while minimizing the number of shuffles I would need to perform.

I have one giant RDD that I have broken down into individual buckets and cartesianed for the point of internal comparison

The basic idea I have so far is something along the line of:

```
val r:RDD[Int, T]
val buckets = List(0 to n).map(a => r.filter(key == a))
buckets.map(_.cartesian().map(//internal comparison))
```

But then I am lost, because if I were to do something along the lines of `buckets.map(_.reduce(//reduction))` that would initiate a large number of shuffles which strike me as inefficient, especially considering that I would eventually want to reduce the results of all of those reductions.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can approach this issue?

Edit:

My overall goal is to be compare all values within an RDD with a smarter algorithm than a simple cartesian.

The basic idea is that the values are bucketized such that I am guaranteed that certain buckets are not similar to eachother, so I only need to compare the buckets that are likely to be similar to each other.

The buckets would in real life be something like:

```
val partitions:List[List[Int]] = clusterSimilarBuckets()
val buckets = partitions.map(a => r.filter{case(key, v) =. a.contains(key)})
```

Comment: Can you also highlight what is your overall goal?

Comment: Hi @RaduIonescu , I have modified the question to highlight the overall goal.

Comment: If you want to compare __all values__ just use Cartesian. While it is inefficient you simply cannot do better than that.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are trying to work something around the concept of Hash join.

My solution would be to repartition by a custom partitioner that is based on your bucket algorithm (or even better to use coalesce if you plan on decresing the number of partitions). If you plan on using the same bucket for multiple comparisons, I would consider replicating the bucket. Take into account that this step does involve some shuffeling.

After this you can use mapPartitions to run an expensive algorithm of comparing every element within a partition, which because of the previous step are all from similar buckets.

Answer (score 0):

You should also consider adapting [Locality Sensitive Hashing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locality-sensitive_hashing) to your use case, as it uses a number of hashers so that two elements belong to the same bucket with high probability. A better explanation of LSH is [chapter 3 of Mining Massive Datasets book](http://www.mmds.org/#ver21). Quick googling also revealed an [LSH implementation for Spark](https://github.com/mrsqueeze/spark-hash).